# Calling a two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

I am nowhere near complete with this code it is just a template and  I have not finished formatting my code. I am having trouble calling the message part of the array in my other class. I basically have an if/else statement saying when roomId = some#, it will outprint the message the correlates to the # from the array. I am just having trouble understanding how to call the array. Eclipse is throwing me an error in the if/else statement under "grid" saying grid cannot be resolved to a variable. I also tried calling the array method inside the method that the statements are in.Thanks for the help guys.

```
    public class location{
        public int roomId;
        public String name, message;

        public location() {
          roomId = 0;
        }
        public location(String name, int roomId, String message){
          this.name = name;
          this.roomId = roomId;
          this.message = message;
        }
        public void LocArray() {
          location[][] grid = new location[4][4];
          grid [1][0] = new location("LABORATORY", 0, "You're in the lab.");
          grid [2][0] = new location("DUNGEON", 1, "You entered the dungeon.");
          grid [3][0] = new location("COURTYARD ENTRANCE",2,"You have left the dungeon out the backdoor. Either head east and search the courtyard maze, or travel north back to the dungeon");
          grid [3][1] = new location("FIRST PATH", 3,"You have now entered the courtyard, either continue east or move north.");
          grid [3][2] = new location("DEADEND", 4,"You have reached a deadend that has a Magic Shop. Go inside and explore it.");
          grid [3][3] = new location ("MAGIC SHOP", 5, "Search around the Magic Shop and see what there is. When you're done searching continue through the maze.");
          grid [2][1] = new location("SECOND PATH",6,"Search the surroundings for items that will help you get into the locked room, then keep moving.");
          grid [2][2] = new location("END MAZE", 7, "You've made it to the end of the courtyard. There seems to be a cave in the distance; go check it out.");
          grid [1][2] = new location("CAVE",8,"Explore the cave to find the remaining items that will lead to your freedom.");
          grid [0][0] = new location("EXIT",9,"This room will lead to your freedom, but you need the three essential items that will open this door.");
        }
}
```

---

```
 //This is a different class called projectTwo.
 while (stillPlaying) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    userInput = scan.nextLine();
    if (roomId == 0){
        if (userInput.equals("n")) {
            System.out.println(grid[2][0].message);
            roomId = 1; // Moves user from location 0 to 1

        }
```

Comment: "I have not finished formatting my code". It's a lot easier if you do it as you go :)

Comment: `grid` is a local variable in `LocArray()`. You can't reference it from anywhere else.

Comment: On a more serious note, you declared `grid` inside the `LocArray()` function in `location`, so there's no way you can access it from anywhere else. Make it a member variable (`public location[][] grid;` up at the top) and then call it with `location.grid`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon and for the formatting i got ripped a new one on my last post for formatting, meanwhile this is my first Java class so I am new to this haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grid` variable is declared inside the `locArray` method.

You can't call it in another method or in an another method inside another class.